# How to add the 2 different column values within a case statement in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Customer table in which I store how much money is spent by each customer on each product.
(Like in the first table given in the attached image)

[image]

What I want is to find how much money is spend for bundle product like in the second table.

This just a sample query I wrote for example

```
  select EmailAddress 
       , case when Books>0 and Movies>0 then sum(Books + Movies)  end as Books_Movies
       , case when Books>0 and Games>0 then sum(Books + Games)  end as Books_Games
       , case when Movies>0 and Games>0 then sum(Movies + Games) end as Books_Music
       
    from Customers
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: so whats the issue youre facing?

Comment: this line : case when Books>0 and Movies>0 then sum(Books + Movies)  end as Books_Movies , I cannot add the 2 columns

Comment: Just do an `Books + Movies` rather than the `sum()`

Comment: Do **not**, **never**, **never ever** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**.

Comment: These are not tables (in a RDBMS sense). These are extracts from spreadsheets. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are complicating your solution while it is as simple as this:

```
select EmailAddress 
       , (Books + Movies) as Books_Movies
       , (Books + Games) as Books_Games
       , (Movies + Games) as Books_Music       
from Customers
```